# C++ getting polymorphic behavior with class members and smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class setup:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void show() { // "show A" }
}

class B : A {
public:
  void show() override { // "show B"}
}

class MainClass {
public:
  MainClass(const A &myA) : myPolymorphicClass(std::make_shared<A>(myA)) {}
  void doShow() {
    myPolymorphicClass.show();
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<A> myPolymorphicClass;
}

int main {
   A myA;
   B myB;
   MainClass myAClass(myA);
   myClass.doShow(); // Will print "show A"

   MainClass myBClass(myB);
   myClass.doShow(); // Will also print "show A"
}
```

I want the corresponding show() to be called, but it's not quite working. I know it's because I'm doing make_shared of A which will point towards A's show() rather than B's, but if I do make_shared of B then I'll have the opposite problem. How can I setup this class so I get the polymorphic behavior I want?

Also I'm pretty sure I could get this working with raw pointers, but I'm really trying to get this to work with smart pointers.

Many thanks!

Comment: You would have the same problem with raw pointers. You need a virtual cloning function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with

```
MainClass(const A &myA) : myPolymorphicClass(std::make_shared<A>(myA)) {}
```

Here, you use `std::make_shared<A>(myA)` which means no matter what `myA` referse to, you are only going to create the `A` part of it in the pointer, which means you will always call the `A` version of the function because all you have is an `A`.  What you need is a template like

```
template <typename T>
MainClass(const T &myA) : myPolymorphicClass(std::make_shared<T>(myA)) {}
```

And now you will create a pointer to the derived class, and that will get stored in `myPolymorphicClass`.  If you want to can even add some SFINAE to the template to constrain `T` to being derived from `A` like

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A,T>, bool> = true>
MainClass(const T &myA) : myPolymorphicClass(std::make_shared<T>(myA)) {}
```

You can see all of this working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/303cd580cdc6689b)

Comment: There is still issue with `B b; A& ref = b; MainClass m(ref);`. `clone` seems the only viable solution.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed. I didn't really consider templates for a few reasons. 1) I didn't know how to limit template types to subclasses of A. and 2) I didn't want to have to specify the template type when created an instance of MainClass.

Your answer solved both of these issues though with SFINAE for #1 and the apparent template type deduction that's happening in #2.

Many thanks!